# Pythagorean Theorem Special Case

Tags: pythagorean-triples

I was hoping you could help me prove the following:

for the case of all $3, 4, 5$ special right triangles, like $6, 8, 10$ and $3\sqrt2, 4\sqrt2, 5\sqrt2$, etc., the relationship

$a/3+b=c$

is always true.

Or can you find a counterexample? I believe it to be true always but am looking for a formal proof.

It is much easier to work with than

$a^2+b^2=c^2.$

Please prove me right :)

Comment: Hint:  for these triangles, $a=3s, b=4s, $ and $c=5s$; what's $a/3+b$ then?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks much! You helped :)

Comment: You may find it helpful to know that these are **not** the only possible Pythagorean triples (e.g., another is given by $5,\,12,\,13$ and it has been proven that there are infinitely many "distinct" triples).

Comment: It is always the case that, for $A^2+B^2=C^2$, one is divisible by $3$, one is divisible by $4$, and one is divisible by $5$. In the example $(5,12,13$, $B$ is divisible by $3$ and $4$, while $A$ is divisible by $5$. Note that $5+\frac {12}{3}\ne 13.$

Answer (score 2):

It's true!   If $a=3s, b=4s, $ and $c=5s$, then $a/3+b=s+4s=5s=c$.

To avoid misunderstanding, it should be noted that there are Pythagorean triples not of this form;

one such example is $5, 12, 13$.

Comment: I just saw your edited answer including the same triple I put in my comment. $+1$

Comment: @Clayton:   Thanks.  It's the triple with the smallest $a$ besides $3$

Comment: @AndyImm:  consider $8, 15, 17$

Comment: @AndyImm: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Examples) article might help you determine your answer. It has a small table of some of the Pythagorean triples.

Comment: Thanks @Clayton and @J.W.Tanner!  Awesome, so 5x/5+12x=13x works too as:
ax/a+bx=cx
This is the case for the following too:
(3, 4, 5)(5, 12, 13)(7, 24, 25)(9, 40, 41)(11, 60, 61)(13, 84, 85)(15, 112, 113)(17, 144, 145)(19, 180, 181)(21, 220, 221)(23, 264, 265)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the two cases:
$$1) \ \begin{cases}a=m^2-n^2\\ b=2mn \\ c=m^2+n^2\end{cases} \qquad 2) \ \begin{cases}a=2mn\\ b= m^2-n^2\\ c=m^2+n^2\end{cases}$$
For case 1:
$$\frac{a}{3}+b=c \iff \frac{m^2-n^2}{3}+2mn=m^2+n^2 \iff m^2+2n^2=3mn \iff \\
(m-n)^2=m(m-n) \iff m=2n\\
\begin{cases}a=3n^2\\ b=4n^2\\ c=5n^2\end{cases}$$
For case 2:
$$\frac{a}{3}+b=c \iff \frac{2mn}{3}+m^2-n^2=m^2+n^2 \iff mn=3n^2 \iff m=3n\\
\begin{cases}a=6n^2\\ b=8n^2\\ c=10n^2\end{cases}$$
Note: $n\in \mathbb R, n\ne 0$, in particular, for $n=\sqrt[4]{2}$, case 1 is $3\sqrt{2},4\sqrt{2},5\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that may help you find the triples you want. I use the negative from the radical because the positive would yield $n=m$ and that would result in trivial triples such as $0,8,8$.

$$\frac{m^2-n^2}{3}+2mn=(m^2+n^2)$$
$$m^2-n^2+6mn=3m^2+3n^2)$$
$$4n^2-6mn+2m^2=0=2n^2-3mn+m^2$$

$$\text{For the }2^{nd}\text{ degree equation above }\quad a=2\quad b=-3m\quad c=m^2$$

$$\text{Solving for n we get: }\quad n=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{3m\pm\sqrt{9m^2-4*2*m^2}}{2*2}=\frac{3m\pm\sqrt{m^2}}{4}=\frac{m}{2}$$

You can generate a triple whenever $n=\frac{m}{2}$ is an integer so $m$ can be any even number. Here are samples with $m$ ranging from $2$ to $26$:

$$3,4,5\quad 
12,16,20\quad 
27,36,45\quad 
48,64,80\quad 
75,100,125\quad 
108,144,180\quad 
147,196,245\quad 
192,256,320\quad 
243,324,405\quad 
300,400,500\quad 
363,484,605\quad 
432,576,720\quad 
507,676,845\quad$$

Note, using the $+$ side of the equation generates $m=n$ resulting in a trivial triple where $A=0$.